# Tkinter button click doesn't trigger function

Tags: python, tkinter, button

Hi all and thanks in advance for all people willing to dive into this subject.

I'm implementing a simple GUI with Tkinter with MVC pattern (not sure I'm doing it right).
Thus, I have several files working together :

- Controller : Main / ControllerHome
- Model : irrelevant here
- View : Main / Root / ViewHome

The main files are handling all the other same category files (in View Main, I call Root and ViewHome).

I created several widgets for my ViewHome (labels and buttons) but am unable to make them work.
I define the button appearance and place them in the ViewHome file and configure their behaviour in the ControllerHome file.
I checked that the buttons do hold the method I configured (the prints I used to check are commented)
Despite my tries and searches for the past 3 days, I'm not able to make it work and don't understand where the issue stands, is it a design flaw, a problem with the inheritance of my buttons, a small parameter i forgot somewhere, the event getting lost ?

REDUCED TO ONE FILE :

```
import tkinter as tk

########    VIEW    ########
class View:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Root()
        self.frames = {}
        self.frame = None
        self.ViewHome = ViewHome(self.root)

        self._add_frames(ViewHome, "home")

        # print(self.ViewHome.button_newcase['command'])

    def _add_frames(self, Frame, name):
        self.frames[name] = Frame(self.root)
        self.frames[name].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    def switch(self, name):
        self.frame = self.frames[name]
        self.frame.tkraise()

    """
    def create_assistant(self):
        print("assistant create")
        self.viewCreate_assistant = View_createCase_assistant()
    """

    def start_mainloop(self):
        # print(self.ViewHome.button_newcase['command'])
        # self.ViewHome.button_newcase.invoke()
        self.root.mainloop()


class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Image Comparison")
        self.configure(background="grey")
        self.geometry(f"400x200")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


class ViewHome(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        # Define the view structure
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Create the buttons
        self.button_newcase = ButtonAction(self, text='New case')
        self.button_newcase.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        # self.button_newcase.invoke()


class ButtonAction(tk.Button):

    def __init__(self, Frame, text):
        self.background = "#0066cc"
        self.activebackground = "#0099ff"
        self.padx = 50
        self.pady = 50
        self.borderwidth = 5
        self.width = 20
        super().__init__(Frame, background=self.background, width=self.width, activebackground=self.activebackground,
                         padx=self.padx, pady=self.pady, text=text, relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=self.borderwidth)

    def setcommand(self, command):
        self.config(command=command)

############################

########    CONTROLLER  ########

class Controller:
    def __init__(self, model, view):
        self.view = view
        self.model = model

        self.controller_home = ControllerHome(model, view)

        # print(self.view.ViewHome.button_newcase['command'])

        self.view.switch("home")

    def start(self):
        # print(self.view.ViewHome.button_newcase['command'])
        self.view.start_mainloop()


class ControllerHome:
    def __init__(self, model, view):
        self.model = model
        self.view = view
        self._bind()

    def _bind(self):
         self.view.ViewHome.button_newcase.config(command=self.newCase)
        #self.view.ViewHome.button_newcase.bind('<Button-1>', self.newCase())
        # self.view.ViewHome.button_newcase.invoke()
        # self.view.ViewHome.button_newcase.setcommand(self.newCase)

    # Home page buttons functions
    def newCase(self):
        print("new button ok")

################################

########    MODELS  ########


############################


def main():
    # model=Case()
    model = None
    view = View()

    controller = Controller(model, view)
    # view.ViewHome.button_newcase.invoke()
    # print(view.ViewHome.button_newcase['command'])
    controller.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

ALL FILES :
Here are the files I'm working with (I don't include the Models files as I don't think they are relevant here), hoping someone can help me find an answer :

My folder structure :

- main.py
- Controller
  - main.py
  - ControllerHome.py
- View
  - main.py
  - ViewHome.py
- Models

main.py

```
from Models.case import Case
from Views.main import View
from Controllers.main import Controller

def main():
    model=Case()
    view=View()

    controller=Controller(model,view)
    #view.ViewHome.button_newcase.invoke()
    #print(view.ViewHome.button_newcase['command'])
    controller.start()

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Controller/Main.py

```
from .home import ControllerHome

class Controller:
    def __init__(self, model, view):
        self.view = view
        self.model = model

        self.controller_home = ControllerHome(model, view)
        #print(self.view.ViewHome.button_newcase['command'])

        self.view.switch("home")


    def start(self):
        print(self.view.ViewHome.button_newcase['command'])
        self.view.start_mainloop()
```

Controller/home.py

```
class ControllerHome:
    def __init__(self, model, view):
        self.model=model
        self.view=view
        self._bind()


    def _bind(self):

        self.view.ViewHome.button_newcase.config(command=self.newCase)
        #self.view.ViewHome.button_newcase.bind('<Button-1>', self.newCase())
        #self.view.ViewHome.button_newcase.setcommand(self.newCase)

        #self.view.ViewHome.button_newcase.invoke()

        self.view.ViewHome.button_loadcase.config(command=self.loadCase)
        self.view.ViewHome.button_deletecase.config(command=self.deleteCase)
        self.view.ViewHome.button_activatecase.config(command=self.activateCase)
        self.view.ViewHome.button_workcase.config(command=self.workCase)

    # Home page buttons functions
    def newCase(self):
        print("newCase ok")

    def loadCase(self):
        print("load button ok")
        
    def deleteCase(self):
        print("delete case ok")

    def activateCase(self):
        print("activate case ok")

    def workCase(self):
        print("work case ok")
```

View/main.py

```
from .root import Root
from .home import ViewHome

class View:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Root()
        self.frames = {}
        self.frame = None
        self.ViewHome = ViewHome(self.root)

        self._add_frames(ViewHome,"home")

        #self.switch("home")

        #print(self.ViewHome.button_newcase['command'])


    def _add_frames(self, Frame, name):
        self.frames[name] = Frame(self.root)
        self.frames[name].grid(row=0, column=0,sticky='nsew')

    def switch(self, name):
        self.frame=self.frames[name]
        self.frame.tkraise()
    """
    def create_assistant(self):
        print("assistant create")
        self.viewCreate_assistant = View_createCase_assistant()
    """

    def start_mainloop(self):
        #print(self.ViewHome.button_newcase['command'])
        #self.ViewHome.button_newcase.invoke()
        self.root.mainloop()
```

View/home.py

```
from tkinter import *

class ViewHome(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):

        super().__init__(root)
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        # Define app and components colors
        self.color_menu_background = "#008A00"
        self.color_app_background = "#B2C9AB"
        self.color_label_message = "#666666"

        # Define the view structure
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)

        # Create the menu bar / not working
        self.menu_bar = Menu(self)
        self.menu_file = Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff=0, background=self.color_menu_background)
        self.menu_file.add_command(label="Not a function")
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Empty", menu=self.menu_file)

        # Create the buttons
        self.button_newcase = ButtonAction(self, text='New case')
        self.button_newcase.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.button_loadcase = ButtonAction(self, text='Load case')
        self.button_loadcase.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.button_activatecase = ButtonAction(self, text='Activate case')
        self.button_activatecase.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.button_deletecase = ButtonAction(self, text='Delete case')
        self.button_deletecase.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.button_workcase = ButtonAction(self, text='Work case')
        self.button_workcase.grid(row=4, column=4, sticky='nsew')

        # Create the message box
        self.label_message = Label(self, text="Message here", background=self.color_label_message)
        self.label_message.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky="nsew")

        # Create the informations box
        self.frame_informations = BoxInformations(self)
        self.frame_informations.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=4, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')

        self.button_newcase.invoke()

class ButtonAction(Button):
    background = "#0066cc"
    activebackground = "#0099ff"
    padx = 50
    pady = 50
    borderwidth = 5
    width=20
    def __init__(self, Frame, text):
        super().__init__(Frame, background=self.background, width=self.width, activebackground=self.activebackground, padx=self.padx, pady=self.pady, text=text, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=self.borderwidth)

    def setcommand(self, command):
        self.config(command=command)

class BoxInformations(Frame):
    background="#666699"
    def __init__(self, Frame):
        super().__init__(Frame, borderwidth=5, relief=RIDGE, bg=self.background)
        # Configure the info box
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)

        # Create elements of the info box
        self.label_info = Label(self, text="Loaded case informations", bg=self.background, border=5)
        self.label_info.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')

        self.label_casename = Label(self, text='Case name', bg=self.background, borderwidth=5)
        self.label_casename.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.label_casenamevalue = Label(self, bg=self.background, borderwidth=5)
        self.label_casenamevalue.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')

        self.label_filesnb = Label(self, text='Number of files', bg=self.background, borderwidth=5)
        self.label_filesnb.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.label_filesnbvalue = Label(self, bg=self.background, borderwidth=5)
        self.label_filesnbvalue.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='nsew')

        self.label_filesdone = Label(self, text='Files done', bg=self.background, borderwidth=5)
        self.label_filesdone.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.label_filesdonevalue = Label(self, bg=self.background, borderwidth=5)
        self.label_filesdonevalue.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='nsew')

        self.label_originfolder = Label(self, text='Origin folder', bg=self.background, borderwidth=5)
        self.label_originfolder.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='nsew')
        self.label_originfoldervalue = Label(self, bg=self.background, borderwidth=5)
        self.label_originfoldervalue.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky='nsew')

        self.label_savefolder = Label(self, text='Saved folder', bg=self.background, borderwidth=5)
        self.label_savefolder.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky='nsew')
        self.label_savefoldervalue = Label(self, bg=self.background, borderwidth=5)
        self.label_savefoldervalue.grid(row=2, column=4, sticky='nsew')
```

View/root.py

```
from tkinter import *

class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Image Comparison")
        self.configure(background="grey")
        self.geometry(f"1500x1000")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
```

Any help is appreciated ! :)

Comment: this really smeels of Overengineering. 
Try to create a minimal reproducible example: one single file, with all needed classes (likely no more than 2), that reproduce your problem - then people will be able to help you. Chances are that on trying to reduce the problem to the minimal reproducible example, you may find what is wired incorrectly there.

Comment: Note that although you use at least 2 indirection levels above what would be needed for a sane Python project, at the file with the UI you do `from tkinter import *`, which is an horrible practice, as it will bring hundreds of names into your module namespace. Just use `import tkinter as tk` and prefix any tkinter thing with `tk.` - that will make your code much more readable.

Comment: This is just far too much code. Please try to reduce it down to a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback ! I edited the code so it is a single file now and removed all non necessary code (I hope it is reduced enough to make it more readable). I am still getting the same behaviour, could me help me find out what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: I added "print(self.button_newcase)" to the ViewHome class. The output: ".!viewhome.!buttonaction" and ".!viewhome2.!buttonaction". You create two frames.

Comment: I added "print(self.view.ViewHome.button_newcase)" in ControllerHome - def _bind(self).  The output:  .!viewhome.!buttonaction. This is the button from the first frame.

Comment: If you set some unique frame name, you will see that the button command will work. ViewHome class -> super().__init__(root, name="view_home"). However, this is not an option. You need to rethink your view creation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for finding it out ! So there was a flaw in my design, I'm gonna work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have created two instances of `ViewHome` inside `View` class:

- first instance: `self.ViewHome = ViewHome(self.root)`
- second instance when executing `self._add_frames(ViewHome, "home")`

Only the second instance is visible (it overlaps the first instance), but you configure the `command` option on the first instance.  Therefore when you click the visible instance (the second one), nothing is done.

You can return the instance created from `_add_frames()` and assign to `self.ViewHome`:

```py
class View:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Root()
        self.frames = {}
        self.frame = None
        #self.ViewHome = ViewHome(self.root)

        self.ViewHome = self._add_frames(ViewHome, "home")

        # print(self.ViewHome.button_newcase['command'])

    def _add_frames(self, Frame, name):
        self.frames[name] = Frame(self.root)
        self.frames[name].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        # return the newly created frame
        return self.frames[name]

    ...
```

Note that you should remove `self.grid(...)` inside `ViewHome.__init__()` as it is not necessary because `.grid(...)` will be executed inside `View._add_frames()`.